# ASP.Net form Wizard Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm using an ASP.Net form Wizard which has three steps. In each step there are required fields. In steps 1 and 2 when the "Next" button is clicked the validation works. Error messages are displayed next to fields which are required. I have a couple of required fields in step 3 but when the "Finish" button is clicked it doesn't validate the required fields in this last step. Not sure what I'm missing.

I have the outline of my wizard below:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" NavigationStyle-CssClass="form_nav_style" FinishCompleteButtonText="Next" OnFinishButtonClick="cmd_UserSession" FinishDestinationPageUrl="~/mypage.aspx" OnNextButtonClick="cmd_PrcntSalesValue" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                // required field validator works
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2">
                // required field validator works
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="Step_3" runat="server" StepType="Finish">
                // required field validators are not working and form is submitted
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" StepType="Complete">

            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
<StartNextButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-custom-sm" />
        <StepPreviousButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-inverse btn-custom-sm" />
        <StepNextButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-custom-sm" />
        <FinishPreviousButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-inverse btn-custom-sm" />
        <FinishCompleteButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-success btn-custom-sm" />
    </asp:Wizard>
```

Comment: i'm not to familiar with the wizard, but can it be a possibility that on a StepNextButton event the validation occurs and on a FinishCompleteButton it doesn't?

Comment: I did work around this issue. I added my own asp.net button to step 3 of the form, and used Page.IsValid in the codebehind. I had to hide the FinishCompleteButton that is generated by the wizard but it works. I wonder it if would work if I changed step 3 StepType to Next and then added the CompleteWizardStep?